# Terraform interpolation of locals map with key defined in a variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

### Terraform interpolation of locals map with key defined in a variable

Objective:
Define preset sizing labels in variable, provisioning of resources uses preset values from locals map variable

```
var "define_size" {
  description = "Select either small, medium, large"
  default = "large"
}


locals {

  small = {
    volume_gb = 1
    volume_count = 1
  }

  medium = {
    volume_gb = 20
    volume_count = 5
  }

  large = {
    volume_gb = 500
    volume_count = 10
  }

}


resource "aws_ebs_volume" "example" {
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  size              = ??????
}
```

**Attempts:**

- `size = local.$var.define_size.volume_gb`. Obvious bad syntax results in "Error: Invalid character." and "Error: Invalid attribute name" referring to the $ character.
- `size = local.${var.define_size}.volume_gb`. Obvious bad syntax results in "Error: Invalid character." and "Error: Invalid attribute name" referring to the $ character.
- `size = "${local[var.define_size].volume_gb}"`. "Error: Invalid reference. A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name."
- `size = tostring("local.${var.define_size}.volume_gb")` this renders correctly but as a string and not a resource reference `"local.large.volume_gb"`
- `format("%#v",tostring("local.${var.define_size}.volume_gb"))` this renders partially correctly but as string with escape characters and not resource `"\"local.large.volume_gb\""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want key-based access you should make the `locals` definition something that works with keys, e.g. a `map`:

```
locals {
  sizes = {
    small = {
      volume_gb = 1
      volume_count = 1
    }
    medium = {
      volume_gb = 20
      volume_count = 5
    }
    large = {
      volume_gb = 500
      volume_count = 10
    }
  }
}
```

and then access that using `local.sizes[var.define_size].volume_gb`

Comment: Super obvious now, can't believe I wasted time on the other attempts. Thanks @luk2302

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Luk2302 for the answer, I was also looking this. I cannot comment so I create another answer.
For my case, I read a list from json file, and then depend on the env, it will get the correct value.

power.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "power": {
      "dev" : 1,
      "sit" : 2,
      "uat" : 3,
      "prod" : 4
    }
  }
]
```

In the tf file, I use as below

```
locals {
  power = jsondecode(file("power.json"))
}

resource "aws_example" "power" {
  count = length(local.power.*.name)
  power = local.power[count.index].power[var.env]
}
```

Depending on the input var.env, the "power" will have value 1, 2, 3, or 4